# opencl- vector wise bit twiddling

Tags: vector, bit-manipulation, opencl

I read some on-line post and papers for removing If-statement, and bit twiddling(bit-manipulation) is one of solution for that.

Can I use bit twiddling with opencl(or cuda) vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. All operators in OpenCL are extended to vector data types. You can read more about it in the [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf#page=217).

Also, you might be interested in looking at the `select` [function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf#page=268).